# Good introductory reference for Bayesian Non-parametric (Dirichlet Process / Chinese Restaurant Process)

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, non-parametric, bayesian-nonparametric

I am looking for a recommendation for basic introductory material on Bayesian Non-parametric methods, specifically Dirichlet Process / Chinese Restaurant Process. I am looking for material which covers the modeling part as well as the inference part from ground-up.

Most of the material I found on the internet has slightly advanced material and they skip the inference part, which is usually harder to grasp.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend Tamara Broderick's 3-part tutorial series from MLSS. She explains both modeling + inference using these methods from the ground up and focuses on the intuition.

Links to [part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kKZkNUvsJ4M), [part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oPcv8MaESGY), and [part 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HpcGlr19vNk).